# Set up a proxy with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to write a webserver (proxy?) so that I can make requests to, say, `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` which would transparently return the response from `https://www.gyford.com/foo/bar`.

The python script below works for a web page itself, but some kinds of files aren't returned (e.g. https://www.gyford.com/static/hines/js/site-340675b4c7.min.js ). If I manually request that file, while this server's running, like:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/static/hines/js/site-340675b4c7.min.js')
```

then I get:

> 'Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',)

So I guess I need to handle gzipped files differently but I can't work out how.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import requests

HOST_NAME = 'localhost'
PORT_NUMBER = 8080
TARGET_DOMAIN = 'www.gyford.com'

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        host_domain = '{}:{}'.format(HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)

        host = self.headers.get('Host').replace(host_domain, TARGET_DOMAIN)

        url = ''.join(['https://', host, self.path])

        r = requests.get(url)

        self.send_response(r.status_code)

        for k,v in r.headers.items():
            self.send_header(k, v)

        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write( bytes(r.text, 'UTF-8') )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
```

**EDIT:** Here's the output of `print(r.headers)`:

> {'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'gunicorn/19.7.1', 'Date': 'Wed, 26 Sep 2018 13:43:43 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript; charset="utf-8"', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=60, public', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 20 Sep 2018 16:11:29 GMT', 'Etag': '"5ba3c6b1-6be"', 'Content-Length': '771', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Via': '1.1 vegur'}

Comment: To be clear: Are the output form the client `r = requests.get(...? `The `r.header` look ok for a `gzip` file, but you requests `.js`? Please explaine. Verify the `'Content-Length': '771'`, are this the length of `gzip` or `.js`?

Comment: The `len()` of both `r.text` and `r.content` is `1726`. Yes, I request a `.js` file, which is served gzipped by [transport level compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: I need to handle gzipped files differently.

I wonder, how this could work for a web page itself, but assuming some magic browser handling.

---

> What you are doing:
>
> ```
>     r = requests.get(url)
> ```
>
> You get the url content, automatically decode the gzip and deflate transfer-encodings.
>
> ```
>     self.wfile.write( bytes(r.text, 'UTF-8') )
> ```
>
> You, write the decoded `r.text`, encoded as `bytes`, this is not the same as Transfer Encoding.

Change the following:
**Read and write as raw stream of bytes** – it does not transform the response content.
You can use this also for other data e.g. "html" requests.

```
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    ...
    self.wfile.write(r.raw.read())
```

Note from [docs.python-requests.org](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content):
Read the chapter about **Raw Response Content** also.
If you want to stream very large data, you have to **chunk** while reading.
[image]

> **Note**: This are the **default** Headers, `python-requests` are using.
>            There is already a  **'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'** Header, so no action needed on the client side.
>
> ```
> {'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 
>  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.11.1', 
>  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
>  'Connection': 'close', 
>  'Host': 'httpbin.org'}
> }
> ```

Comment: Magic, thanks! I'd tried various things and none of them worked. Thanks for taking the time to think through this for me.